# pgrep in linux only identify 15 bytes proc name

Tags: linux, shell

in my Linux , while I run shell :  ps -ef | grep Speed  , I got the following :

```
myid 143410  49092  0 10:21 pts/12   00:00:00 ./OutSpeedyOrderConnection
myid 145492  49053  0 10:35 pts/11   00:00:00 ./SpeedyOrderConnection
```

That means , the pid of these 2 process are 143410 and 145492  .

Then I run shell :  pgrep -l Speed   , I got the following :

```
143410 OutSpeedyOrderC
145492 SpeedyOrderConn
```

and I run shell : pgrep OutSpeedyOrderC , I got :

```
143410
```

pgrep OutSpeedyOrderCo  will get nothing !!!!!

look like pgrep will only identify 15 bytes of processname ,
anything I can do to get the right answer while I run 
pgrep OutSpeedyOrderConnection  ?!

Comment: Use the `-f` flag to force matching against the full command line?

Comment: Interesting.  I get the same behavior as the OP and using `-f`, as suggested by @EtanReisner, solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I see similar behavior as well and using `-f` "fixes" it. I haven't looked to see but it would seem the OP is correct that, by default, `pgrep` has a very small buffer for the "process name" and using `-f` is necessary to have it consider the full process name (as part of using the whole command line).